# Determining bar width, with a 3d matrix

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have my data as follows:

```
var data = [[-5,7,10],[10,15,25],[-18,-14,-6]];

var margin = {top: 0, right: 30, bottom: 80, left: 30},
        width = 180 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 295 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x0 = Math.max(-d3.min(data[0]), d3.max(data[2]));
var x = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([-x0, x0])
        .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
.domain(d3.range(data.length))
.rangeRoundBands([0, height], .2);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.selectAll(".bar")
        .data(data)
      .enter().append("rect")     
        .style("fill", "steelblue")
        .attr("x", function(d, i) { return x(Math.min(0, d[0])); })
        .attr("y", function(d, i) { return y(i); })
        .attr("width", function(d, i) { return Math.abs(x(d[2]) - x(d[0])); })
        .attr("height", y.rangeBand())
        .append("rect");

//y axis
svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "y axis")
.append("line")
.attr("x1", x(0))
.attr("x2", x(0))
.attr("y1", 0)
.attr("y2", height+10);
```

What I want to do is create a bar chart where `data[0]` is the starting point, `data[1]` has a vertical line bisecting the bar and `data[2]` is the max value of the bar. So far, I think I'm covering the first two use cases correctly, but the third one fails. Any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/NPqEm/

Comment: In the future, please make sure to include your code inside your question as well as linking somewhere else - it helps when reading.

Comment: edited, there is also a link to the cod in the jsfiddle